# How to use python to test if a number can hit a series of numbers for X times?

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, series

How do I use python to do the following? For fixed period of time-series data, if it's possible to have any horizontal line (fixed price) crossing the purple line (a series of price) 4 times, return `True` as shown in the following picture.

[image]

If it's not possible to have any horizontal line (fixed price) crossing the purple line (a series of price) 4 times, return `False` as shown in the following picture. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can describe the purple line mathematically then you need to find a
y = f(x) where for a given y you have four or more satisfying x.

Now let's do it with a brute force approach:

```py
max_y = 10.0 # the biggest y the purple line has
min_y = 5.0 # the smallest y purple line has
min_x = 0 # the x the purple line starts
max_x = 100 # the x the purple line ends
delta = 0.01 # the step value for testing every line

def in_purple(x, y):
    # returns if the point (x, y) is in the purple line
    pass

for y in range(min_y, max_y + delta, delta):
    counter = 0
    for x in range(min_x, max_x + delta, delta):
        if in_purple(x, y):
            counter += 1
    if counter >= 4:
        print(y) # prints the y where you have 4 or more coincidences
        break
```